# Cannot catch `file:///` webRequest in chrome extension on Chromebook

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chromebook

Below is a simple extension that works fine on a normal version of chrome. The `onHeadersReceived`, and `onBeforeSendHeaders` catch all requests. However, on a chromebook, it doesn't catch `file:///` requests. Could this have to do with extra security measures on Chromebooks, or something like that? Local html files load fine via the SD card on the chromebook, but the request aren't caught (both the initial html file request, and any local resources like images that are subsequently loaded by that html page).

Edit: Note that I have made sure that the "Allow access to file URLs" checkbox is ticked on the `chrome://extensions` page. Also, it works fine on my non-chromebook laptop even without the `file:///*/*` permissions - the `<all_urls>` permission/filter seems to be enough.

#### background.js:

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details) {
  debugger;
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>", "file:///*/*"]}, ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]);

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details) {
  debugger;
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>", "file:///*/*"]}, ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
```

#### manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "test.",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
    "tabs",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "<all_urls>",
        "file:///*/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: `file://*/*` ? shouldn't that be `file:///*` ?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Fixed. Yeah I've tried `file:///*/*` and `file:///*`. Works fine on my non-chromebook even **without** the `file:///` stuff (`<all_urls>` seems to be enough). I should specify that I have explicitly given the extension permission to access file urls via the `chrome://extensions/` page (there's a checkbox for each extension).

Comment: Check https://crbug.com and report the bug if it's not there.

Comment: Done: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=820326 @wOxxOm if you have a chromebook and have confirmed this doesn't work on it, could you please add your confirmation to the issue?